# Roblox | Help Fix Cutoff GUI's in Billboard GUI

Tags: roblox

Right now, I'm working on Server Fixing Simulator.

I'm working on the Error Popup GUI.

I wanted to add the Error Icon.

The ImageLabel gets cutoff.

The ImageLabel is CutOff! WHAT A WAY ROBLOX MAKES THE GUIs! HOW NICE

[image]

so I need help fixing the Cut-Off GUIs.

Problem Info -

When the Properties Menu looks like this

[image: The Properties]

And the ErrorIcon looks like this.

[image: The Error Icon]

It just makes me mad.

Answer (score 0):

This happens a lot in Roblox. When an image is new, it looks like that for about an hour. I suggest you wait a little bit or upload a new one.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, but this doesn't answer my question. I haven't added a picture on the ImageLabel yet.  The problem is, the Image is cut off when I make the picture go on the Z Axis.

Comment: If you mean that the image is a rectangle but it's supposed to be a square, then the problem is the decal itself. Send me the link to the image.

Comment: uh..  rbxasset://textures/ui/GuiImagePlaceholder.png

Comment: That's not a link, there's no ID in it.

Comment: That's Roblox's Pre-Made image.

Comment: I told you. The problem is not with the image.